# Excel Trust Center blocking "save as .csv"

Tags: excel, csv, save

I'm trying to save a excel worksheet as a .csv or even a tab delimited text file. But the error message "You are attempting to save a file type (Text File) that has been blocked by your File Block settings in your Trust Center." Except I've turned ON  !ALL! of my save permissions in the Trust Center. Then exited Excel and restarted, checked the Trust Center, All permission ON .... same message. Any ideas for me to get this sheet saved as a delimited text file ?

Tried turning on all permissions ... no luck